# how to make ASP.NET 1.1 web app working as child of asp.NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have 2 ASP.NET web app, Webapp2 is ASP.NET 2.0, webapp1 is for ASP.NET 1.1
IIS is on windows server 2008.

I create a website for webapp2. Set application pool for asp.net 2.0

then create web app(add application) webapp1 under webapp2 and set applocation pool as Asp.net 1.1

Set application pool as Asp.NET 1.1 and managed pipeline mode as Integrated, 
Then webapp1 not working. got error as:

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list
```

Set application pool as Asp.NET 1.1 and managed pipeline mode as Classic, 
Then webapp1 not working. got error as:

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'inheritInChildApplications'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
Line 2:  <configuration>
Line 3:  <location path="" inheritInChildApplications="false" >
Line 4:     <system.web>
Line 5:         <!--  DYNAMIC DEBUG COMPILATION
```

If I set application pool Asp.net 2.0 for webapp1, it is working but at some point I got following error:

Previously, webapp1 is under another web app for asp.net 1.1 and working fine(On same server)

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the attribute inheritInChildApplications from the 1.1 apps web.config, as it seems to have been introduced in .net 2.0.

<del>inheritInChildApplications="false"</del>

[see msdn article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.inheritinchildapplications%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)